# How To Code A Hovering Navigation Bar To Appear Only When You Start Scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, css, blogger

I would like to have my hovering/sticky navigation bar appear when a reader/web visitor has scrolled passed the blog header, instead of the navigation bar appearing at all times, as it currently does. I'm not entirely sure how to achieve this affect as I have done research on this but to no avail, but I am certain it is completely doable. I have seen this effect on two blogs, one of which is hosted on Blogger, the URL of these sites are as follows : http://www.theweekendattic.com/ and http://mediamarmalade.com/. The URL to my own blog is as follows : http://www.blankesque.com

The CSS and HTML coding for the hovering navigation bar currently on my site is detailed below :

```
#wctopdropcont{
width:100%;
height:45px;
display:block;
padding: 5.5px 0 0 0;
z-index:100;
top:-2px;
left: 0px;
position: fixed;

background:#f5f5f5;
border-bottom: 1px solid #f0f0f0;
  }

#wctopdropnav{ 
float: left;
width:97%;
height:7px;
display:block;
padding:0px;
}

#wctopdropnav li{
float:left;
list-style:none;
line-height:13px;
padding: 10px 6.5px 6.5px 6.5px;
background:#f5f5f5;
}
#wctopdropnav li a, #wctopdropnav li a:link{
color:#494949;
float: left;
display:block;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-size: 10.5px!important;
font-family: karla, arial!important;
padding: 5px;
text-decoration:none;
font-weight: normal!important;
letter-spacing : 0.09em;
}

#wctopdropnav li:first-child a {
font-weight: bold!important;
margin-left: 20px;
  }

#wctopdropnav li a:hover, #wctopdropnav li a:active,   #wctopdropnav .current_page_item a  {
 color: #a6a6a6;
font-weight: normal;
padding: 5px;
background: #f5f5f5;  
}
#wctopdropnav li li a, #wctopdropnav li li a:link, #wctopdropnav li li a:visited{
font-size: 10.5px;
background:#f5f5f5;
color: #494949;
width: 90px;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0;
line-height: 15px;
position: relative;
}

#wctopdropnav li li a:hover, #wctopdropnav li li a:active {
color: #a6a6a6;
background: #f5f5f5;
filter: #f5f5f5;
}

#wctopdropnav li:hover, #wctopdropnav li.sfhover{
position:static
}   
#socialmediabuttons { 
display: block; 
float: right;  
position: relative;
margin: 0.9% -1% 0 0;
} 
#socialmediabuttons a {  
padding: 0 0 0 18px;
} 
#socialmediabuttons a:hover { 
opacity: 0.4; 
filter: alpha(opacity=40); 
 } 
</style>
<div id='wctopdropcont'>
 <div id='wctopdropnav'>

   <li><a href='http://www.blankesque.com'>Home</a></li>
              <li><a href='http://www.blankesque.com/search/label/Advice'>Advice</a></li>
              <li><a href='http://www.blankesque.com/search/label/Beauty'>Beauty</a></li>
           <li><a href='http://www.blankesque.com/search/label/Fashion'>Fashion</a></li>
              <li><a href='http://www.blankesque.com/search/label/Lifestyle'>Lifestyle</a></li>
           <li><a href='http://www.blankesque.com/search/label/Skin &amp; Hair'>Skin &amp; Hair</a></li>

<div id='socialmediabuttons'>  


<a href='https://www.pinterest.com/blankesque' target='_blank'><img height='20px' src='http://i1379.photobucket.com/albums/ah140/mynamesiram/Mobile%20Uploads/91F98FB1-242C-428E-A472-50F7D511C38E_zpsaiuhz6yb.gif' width='20px'/> 
</a> 


<a href='https://www.twitter.com/' target='_blank'><img height='20px' src='http://i1379.photobucket.com/albums/ah140/mynamesiram/Mobile%20Uploads/923FF7F8-5AA7-4676-935F-2CB5FF465122_zpsmctqg100.gif' width='20px'/></a> 
<a href='http://www.bloglovin.com/blogs/blankesque-14431777' target='_blank'><img height='20px' src='http://i1379.photobucket.com/albums/ah140/mynamesiram/Mobile%20Uploads/7CC1080E-1911-4D0B-B99F-55109C044D54_zps2ky5dfgt.gif' width='20px'/></a> 


<a href='https://instagram.com/' target='_blank'><img height='20px' src='http://i1379.photobucket.com/albums/ah140/mynamesiram/Mobile%20Uploads/C6567CDB-FB01-4F2D-A2FD-D0D875A30B80_zps5mgdqong.gif' width='20px'/></a> 

   </div>

  </div></div>
```

Comment: Any input in this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery fadein/fadeout in **scroll** event:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".navbar").hide();
    $(function () {
        $(window).scroll(function () {
            if ($(this).scrollTop() > 50) {
                $('.navbar').fadeIn();
            } else {
                $('.navbar').fadeOut();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Apologies but Im not very knowledgeable when it comes to coding, where would I have to place this code in my template?

Comment: Add this `<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>` and then my code into `<script></script>` before </body> tag

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me with this, I really appreciate it. I pasted the following <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".navbar").hide();
    $(function () {
        $(window).scroll(function () {
            if ($(this).scrollTop() > 50) {
                $('.navbar').fadeIn();
            } else {
                $('.navbar').fadeOut();
            }
        });
    });
});
</script> just above the </body> tag but it didn't achieve the affect I was looking for.