# Coding A Hovering Navbar To Appear Only When Scrolling

Tags: html, css, blogger

I would like to have my hovering navbar appear when a reader has scrolled passed the blog header, instead of the navbar appearing at all times, as it currently does. I'm not entirely sure how to achieve this affect or where to start. I have seen this effect on two blogs, one of which is hosted on Blogger, the URL of these sites are as follows : http://www.theweekendattic.com/ and http://mediamarmalade.com/. The URL to my own blog is as follows : http://www.blankesque.com

The CSS and HTML coding for the hovering navigation bar currently on my site is detailed below :

```
#wctopdropcont{
width:100%;
height:45px;
display:block;
padding: 5.5px 0 0 0;
z-index:100;
top:-2px;
left: 0px;
position: fixed;

background:#f5f5f5;
border-bottom: 1px solid #f0f0f0;
  }

#wctopdropnav{ 
float: left;
width:97%;
height:7px;
display:block;
padding:0px;
}

#wctopdropnav li{
float:left;
list-style:none;
line-height:13px;
padding: 10px 6.5px 6.5px 6.5px;
background:#f5f5f5;
}
#wctopdropnav li a, #wctopdropnav li a:link{
color:#494949;
float: left;
display:block;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-size: 10.5px!important;
font-family: karla, arial!important;
padding: 5px;
text-decoration:none;
font-weight: normal!important;
letter-spacing : 0.09em;
}

#wctopdropnav li:first-child a {
font-weight: bold!important;
margin-left: 20px;
  }

#wctopdropnav li a:hover, #wctopdropnav li a:active,   #wctopdropnav .current_page_item a  {
 color: #a6a6a6;
font-weight: normal;
padding: 5px;
background: #f5f5f5;  
}
#wctopdropnav li li a, #wctopdropnav li li a:link, #wctopdropnav li li a:visited{
font-size: 10.5px;
background:#f5f5f5;
color: #494949;
width: 90px;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0;
line-height: 15px;
position: relative;
}

#wctopdropnav li li a:hover, #wctopdropnav li li a:active {
color: #a6a6a6;
background: #f5f5f5;
filter: #f5f5f5;
}

#wctopdropnav li:hover, #wctopdropnav li.sfhover{
position:static
}   
#socialmediabuttons { 
display: block; 
float: right;  
position: relative;
margin: 0.9% -1% 0 0;
} 
#socialmediabuttons a {  
padding: 0 0 0 18px;
} 
#socialmediabuttons a:hover { 
opacity: 0.4; 
filter: alpha(opacity=40); 
 } 
</style>
<div id='wctopdropcont'>
 <div id='wctopdropnav'>

   <li><a href='http://www.blankesque.com'>Home</a></li>
              <li><a href='http://www.blankesque.com/search/label/Advice'>Advice</a></li>
              <li><a href='http://www.blankesque.com/search/label/Beauty'>Beauty</a></li>
           <li><a href='http://www.blankesque.com/search/label/Fashion'>Fashion</a></li>
              <li><a href='http://www.blankesque.com/search/label/Lifestyle'>Lifestyle</a></li>
           <li><a href='http://www.blankesque.com/search/label/Skin &amp; Hair'>Skin &amp; Hair</a></li>

<div id='socialmediabuttons'>  


<a href='https://www.pinterest.com/blankesque' target='_blank'><img height='20px' src='http://i1379.photobucket.com/albums/ah140/mynamesiram/Mobile%20Uploads/91F98FB1-242C-428E-A472-50F7D511C38E_zpsaiuhz6yb.gif' width='20px'/> 
</a> 


<a href='https://www.twitter.com/' target='_blank'><img height='20px' src='http://i1379.photobucket.com/albums/ah140/mynamesiram/Mobile%20Uploads/923FF7F8-5AA7-4676-935F-2CB5FF465122_zpsmctqg100.gif' width='20px'/></a> 
<a href='http://www.bloglovin.com/blogs/blankesque-14431777' target='_blank'><img height='20px' src='http://i1379.photobucket.com/albums/ah140/mynamesiram/Mobile%20Uploads/7CC1080E-1911-4D0B-B99F-55109C044D54_zps2ky5dfgt.gif' width='20px'/></a> 


<a href='https://instagram.com/' target='_blank'><img height='20px' src='http://i1379.photobucket.com/albums/ah140/mynamesiram/Mobile%20Uploads/C6567CDB-FB01-4F2D-A2FD-D0D875A30B80_zps5mgdqong.gif' width='20px'/></a> 

   </div>

  </div></div>
```

Comment: You'll need jQuery for this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How To Code A Hovering Navigation Bar To Appear Only When You Start Scrolling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34687237/how-to-code-a-hovering-navigation-bar-to-appear-only-when-you-start-scrolling)

Answer (score 0):

So I suggest you to do this with jquery and jquery.sticky.js plugin that you can 
download here : http://stickyjs.com/

So I changed your code a bit
HTML :

```
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>

<div class="stick" id='wctopdropcont'>
 <div id='wctopdropnav'>

   <li><a href='http://www.blankesque.com'>Home</a></li>
              <li><a href='http://www.blankesque.com/search/label/Advice'>Advice</a></li>
              <li><a href='http://www.blankesque.com/search/label/Beauty'>Beauty</a></li>
           <li><a href='http://www.blankesque.com/search/label/Fashion'>Fashion</a></li>
              <li><a href='http://www.blankesque.com/search/label/Lifestyle'>Lifestyle</a></li>
           <li><a href='http://www.blankesque.com/search/label/Skin &amp; Hair'>Skin &amp; Hair</a></li>

<div id='socialmediabuttons'>  


<a href='https://www.pinterest.com/blankesque' target='_blank'><img height='20px' src='http://i1379.photobucket.com/albums/ah140/mynamesiram/Mobile%20Uploads/91F98FB1-242C-428E-A472-50F7D511C38E_zpsaiuhz6yb.gif' width='20px'/> 
</a> 


<a href='https://www.twitter.com/' target='_blank'><img height='20px' src='http://i1379.photobucket.com/albums/ah140/mynamesiram/Mobile%20Uploads/923FF7F8-5AA7-4676-935F-2CB5FF465122_zpsmctqg100.gif' width='20px'/></a> 
<a href='http://www.bloglovin.com/blogs/blankesque-14431777' target='_blank'><img height='20px' src='http://i1379.photobucket.com/albums/ah140/mynamesiram/Mobile%20Uploads/7CC1080E-1911-4D0B-B99F-55109C044D54_zps2ky5dfgt.gif' width='20px'/></a> 


<a href='https://instagram.com/' target='_blank'><img height='20px' src='http://i1379.photobucket.com/albums/ah140/mynamesiram/Mobile%20Uploads/C6567CDB-FB01-4F2D-A2FD-D0D875A30B80_zps5mgdqong.gif' width='20px'/></a> 

   </div>

  </div></div>
  <br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
```

-s are for scrolling purpose;

JS :

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".stick").sticky({topSpacing:0});
  });
```

CSS:

```
#wctopdropcont{
width:100%;
height:45px;
display:block;
padding: 5.5px 0 0 0;
z-index:100;
top:-2px;
left: 0px;
//just got the fixed position out ;)
background:#f5f5f5;
border-bottom: 1px solid #f0f0f0;
  }

#wctopdropnav{ 
float: left;
width:97%;
height:7px;
display:block;
padding:0px;
}

#wctopdropnav li{
float:left;
list-style:none;
line-height:13px;
padding: 10px 6.5px 6.5px 6.5px;
background:#f5f5f5;
}
#wctopdropnav li a, #wctopdropnav li a:link{
color:#494949;
float: left;
display:block;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-size: 10.5px!important;
font-family: karla, arial!important;
padding: 5px;
text-decoration:none;
font-weight: normal!important;
letter-spacing : 0.09em;
}

#wctopdropnav li:first-child a {
font-weight: bold!important;
margin-left: 20px;
  }

#wctopdropnav li a:hover, #wctopdropnav li a:active,   #wctopdropnav .current_page_item a  {
 color: #a6a6a6;
font-weight: normal;
padding: 5px;
background: #f5f5f5;  
}
#wctopdropnav li li a, #wctopdropnav li li a:link, #wctopdropnav li li a:visited{
font-size: 10.5px;
background:#f5f5f5;
color: #494949;
width: 90px;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0;
line-height: 15px;
position: relative;
}

#wctopdropnav li li a:hover, #wctopdropnav li li a:active {
color: #a6a6a6;
background: #f5f5f5;
filter: #f5f5f5;
}

#wctopdropnav li:hover, #wctopdropnav li.sfhover{
position:static
}   
#socialmediabuttons { 
display: block; 
float: right;  
position: relative;
margin: 0.9% -1% 0 0;
} 
#socialmediabuttons a {  
padding: 0 0 0 18px;
} 
#socialmediabuttons a:hover { 
opacity: 0.4; 
filter: alpha(opacity=40);
```

Here is jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/dp6s9udh/

Comment: Thank you for the help Marko, I really appreciate all your work. However is there another way I can achieve this look without the use of jquery.

Comment: There is no way to do this without jquery if you want to do it when scrolled and why to do it without jquery when most devices that can go online can execute java script :)

Comment: I have downloaded the file that you linked in your first 'answer' and I have followed all the steps however I am unable to save the changes to my template. I keep getting this notification : The element type "br" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</br>".

Comment: well i thought you use it inside some content, so you wouldn't need br's but ok, if it says so then do <br></br> for each :) even thought that isn't correct sintax :)

Comment: and thought you should include jquery.sticky.js in the header , so you need to extract it from that zip to where is your index/default in template

Comment: I have been able to resolve the <br></br> issue however I've got no idea what you mean by extracting something from the zip

Comment: @Jessica have you downloaded jquery.sticky.js ?

Answer (score 0):

Hide the navbar using CSS on initial page load and make it visible when document is scrolled for a particular amount using jQuery.

Add this CSS so it will be hidden by default.

```
#wctopdropcont {
  display: block;
}
```

Add this jQuery in header to make it visible or hidden on scroll.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery(window).scroll(function(){
      var scrollbar = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
      if (scrollbar > 75) {
        jQuery('#wctopdropcont').fadeIn();
      } else {
        jQuery('#wctopdropcont').fadeOut();
      }
  });
});
```

Comment: Apologies but I don't quite understand where I am suppose to add the jQuery code. where about in the header should I place the code?

Comment: @Jessica You can add this script in header or footer of your website. Just make sure you have added [jQuery](http://jquery.com/download/) before this script. Take a look at this article http://javascript.info/tutorial/adding-script-html